# ORMLite or Query across multiple tables

Tags: java, ormlite

I am trying to query a table based on criteria from a join table using ORMLite.

Here is how I would express the query I am trying to write in tsql:

```
select * from media m inner join file f on m.fileId = f.fileId
where m.isNew = 1 OR f.isNew = 1
```

The result should be a list of media records where either the media record or the corresponding file record has isNew = 1.

I have read through the documentation on using OR in ORMLite, but all of the examples use a single table, not joining.  Likewise I have read the documentation on joins, but none of the examples include a where clause that spans both tables.  Is there any way besides a raw query to do this?

I had a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12629645/874782  and it seems to ask the same thing, but the accepted answer produces an AND query, not an OR.  Here is my code that I used to test that theory:

```
public List<Media> getNewMedia() {
    Session session = getSession();
    Account account = session.getSelectedAccount();
    ContentGroup contentGroup = account.getSelectedContentGroup();

    List<Media> results = null;

    try {

        QueryBuilder<Category, Integer> categoryQueryBuilder = getHelper().getCategoryDao().queryBuilder();
        categoryQueryBuilder.where().eq("group_id", contentGroup.getId());

        QueryBuilder<MediaCategory, Integer> mediaCatQb = getHelper().getMediaCategoryDao().queryBuilder();
        mediaCatQb = mediaCatQb.join(categoryQueryBuilder);

        QueryBuilder<FileRecord, Integer> fileQueryBuilder = getHelper().getFileDao().queryBuilder();
        fileQueryBuilder.where().ge("lastUpdated", contentGroup.getLastDownload());

        QueryBuilder<Media, Integer> mediaQb = getHelper().getMediaDao().queryBuilder();
        mediaQb.where().eq("seen", false);
        // join with the media query
        results = mediaQb.join(fileQueryBuilder).join(mediaCatQb).query();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Sql Exception", e);
    }

    return results;
}
```

For the sake of completion, this is querying for a slightly more complex example than the one I gave above, this one expressed in tsql would be

```
select * from Media m join FileRecord f on m.fileRecordId = f.fileRecordId
where m.seen = false OR f.lastUpdated >= lastUpdateDate
```

When I run it, it is actually doing an AND query, which is what I would expect based on two joins with independent where clauses.

I think the key issue is that a where clause is inherently tied to a table, because it is performed on a QueryBuilder object which comes from a Dao that is specific to that table.  How can I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is `joinOr` search for it in the [ORMLite docs](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/).

> Like join(QueryBuilder) but this combines the WHERE statements of two
>   query builders with a SQL "OR".