# Magical join, or refresh multiple objects at once?

Tags: android, ormlite

I have some `Item`s with a foreign key to a parent `Category`. Is there an efficient way to query some Items and get fully populated Category objects?

The only approach I'm aware of is to use `foreignAutoRefresh`, or to refresh the Categories manually after the Item query, but this would result in an extra db hit for EACH Item object.

This can be done with a single JOIN, but if I do that is there any support for automatically building out the Category objects?  Part (maybe all) of the problem is I don't fully understand the QueryBuilder's join functionality, but based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7320091/931277) it sounds like it doesn't do this:

> Notice, however, that you can only get entities from the query builder
>   using this mechanism. If you want to get your two description fields
>   from different objects then you would have to still use a raw-query.

Alternatively, is there a way to refresh a collection of Categories in place with a single query, so that I can take the bare id-only Categories from the Item query and refresh them all?

In case it's of interest, the goal is to display these hierarchically in an [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html#setAdapter(android.widget.ExpandableListAdapter)).  Please let me know if I can provide any more info.  I am comfortable throwing some SQL at it and populating Java objects myself if need be, but I'd rather stay within the framework if possible.