# Simple join with Ormlite within Service Stack

Tags: c#, ormlite-servicestack

Given two basic types:

```
 public class Employee
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long GlobalId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Identifier
{
    public long GlobalId { get; set; }
    public long EmployerId { get; set; }
}
```

How can OrmLite be used to perform the following common query?

```
SELECT Employee.Id, Employee.Name FROM Employee 
INNER JOIN Identifier ON Employee.GlobalId = Identifier.GlobalId
WHERE Identifier.EmployerId = @employerId
```

Comment: Have you seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301418/ormlite-inner-join-on-three-tables so you can do `Employees.join(Identifier)`

Comment: This link gives several join examples - https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/895ce88ae65575f604c19fb6427898baa0af980e/src/SqliteExpressionsTest/JoinTest.cs